# Convert CSV containing nested JSON rows to SQL table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a CSV file with several million rows, and want to load it as a PostgreSQL table. One of the rows in the column 'json_doc' as an example contains:

```
{"id": <>,
 "base": 
    {"ateco": 
        [
            {
            "code": "<>", 
            "rootCode": "<>", 
            "description": "<>"
            }
        ], 
        "founded": "<>", 
        "legalName": "<>", 
        "legalForms": 
            [
                {
                "name": "<>", 
                "level": <>
                }, 
                {
                "name": "<>", 
                "level": <>
                }
            ]
    }, 
 "name": "<>", 
 "people": 
        {
            "items": 
                [
                    {
                    "name": "<>", 
                    "givenName": "<>", 
                    "familyName": "<>"
                    }
                ]
        },
 "country": "<>",
 "locations": {}
 }
```

Which as you can see has many nested dictionaries. And there are several million of these.

I'd like to get this file into an SQL table with even the sub-dictionary values in their own columns. How can I do this? It would seem I have to use some sort of name spacing technique for the nested data as there are some duplicate keys i.e. 'name'.

The data will be analysed using Pandas, but I'd like to get this straight into Postgres if possible. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

The result will look like:

### id | base_ateco_code | etc | base_ateco_legalForms_name | etc |

Unless there are any ideas about this - it's a pretty open project from my employer - I just need to be able to use this information as part of a JOIN with another table.

Many thanks.

Comment: What's the structure of your target table you're thinking about? I see that each of your comma separated values themselves are json arrays. Do you want them to be stored as individual columns? Please explain by showing a final structure of your table(datatype etc ) and a sample row.

Comment: Please add a **short** example and an expected output.

Comment: Added rough table structure, but it's quite flexible, I just need to be able to access each column really, in order to perform a join with another table.

Comment: Postgres has [native support for JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html). Store the JSON as-is. You can set up an index on the JSON column to support fast joins, or you could use SQL in a second step to extract the relevant data from the JSON column into a separate table if necessary.